# How to remove the Silverlight icon in Applications?

Tags: icons

How can I remove the `Silverlight` icon in my `Applications` list? I tried to drag it into trash can but it just won't go.

[image]

Comment: I went in and selected it (actually in `Finder`, not from the grid), then hit "Command + DEL".  Otherwise, you could do it from the Terminal (if all else fails, as a `sudo` if you have it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the finder
2. Open the "Applications"-tab
3. Drag the silverlight-icon into trash

You have to to it within the finder.